# Is there an automatic way to terminate queries writing into a stream/table in KSQL?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

When I drop a table or stream in KSQL using the command `DROP STREAM stream_name;`, I've usually get this information with a specific query number:

```
Cannot drop STREAM_NAME
The following queries read from this source: [].
The following queries write into this source: [CSAS_STREAM_NAME_221]
```

Then I have to terminate the query manually using `TERMINATE CSAS_STREAM_NAME_221`
And then finally I can drop the stream.

Is there a way I can automate this to clean up all not used/bad streams and tables?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this currently (ksqlDB v0.8.1 / Confluent Platform v5.4.1).

Feel free to comment/upvote related issues

- https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/2112
- https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/2177